# Where is a thread's context saved and can it be accessed programmatically (without modifying the kernel)?

Tags: windows, multithreading, kernel, scheduler

[Windows Context Switching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/context-switches)

> The scheduler maintains a queue of executable threads for each
> priority level. These are known as ready threads. When a processor
> becomes available, the system performs a context switch. The steps in
> a context switch are:
>
> - Save the context of the thread that just finished executing.
> - Place the thread that just finished executing at the end of the queue for its priority.
> - Find the highest priority queue that contains ready threads.
> - Remove the thread at the head of the queue, load its context, and execute it.

I don't know much about the topic yet, so I don't know how to elaborate on my question. Where is a thread's context saved, and can it be accessed (edit: read) programmatically (without modifying the kernel)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, What do you think your program could do if it _was_ able to modify the contexts of its own suspended threads?

Comment: @SolomonSlow perhaps not modify, just read for scanning purposes. Cybersecurity tooling.

Comment: Hmm... I am removing my prior comment. I wasn't thinking clearly about the question. It's likely that Windows has a _debugging_ API. (How else could a debugger work in a protected-mode OS?) I don't know where you'd look for that, but that's probably what you want.

Comment: @SolomonSlow it does but both malicious and benign programs attempt to prevent debugging, it's easy to detect the debugger is attached.

Comment: AFAIK, the thread context is stored in the kernel data structures and you cannot directly access to it without privileged rights and very-likely not from the user land. I am not familiar with the Windows kernel, but Linux kernel modules can easily access to the scheduling information, so I guess kernel-mode Windows services could do that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a handle to a thread with the required access rights you can suspend the thread and then call [`GetThreadContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadcontext). When a thread is running the values are in the real CPU registers, when it is not running the context is stored in memory not accessible from usermode.

The context stores the values of various CPU registers, it is only useful to debuggers and advanced features like code injection and error logging.